# Normalization of a table with a one-to-many relation

Tags: mysql, sql

If there is relation between city and region where region -> city is a one-to-many mapping .

Following is the database design:

**City**

1. city_id
2. city_name
3. region_id

**Region**

1. id
2. name

`region_id` is foreign key to the `Region` table

I want to know if **region_id and city_id** are candidate keys. The relation is not in 2 NF due to partial dependency of city_name on candidate key.

How to deal with normalization for one to many mapping?

Comment: If `city_id` is an autoincrement id (you should definitely clear that up, but unless this is some kind of homework question, it should be an autoincrement id to not make your table too complicated), `city_id` is your (only) candidate key for `city` (though `(city_name, region_id)` could be one too, depending on how big your regions are, but I don't think it would make much logical sense) and your table is in 5th normal form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The relation is not in 2 NF due to partial dependency of city_name on candidate key

So does your data look like this?:

```
Region ( key = region_id ):
{ region_id = 'R01', region_name = 'France' };
{ region_id = 'R02', region_name = 'Texas' };

City ( key = ??? ):
{ city_id = 'C01', city_name = 'Paris', region_id = 'R01' };  -- Paris, France
{ city_id = 'C01', city_name = 'Paris', region_id = 'R02' };  -- Paris, Texas
```

In other words, you only want one city named 'Paris' because all Parises are the same entity? I would suggest that is an odd world view!

I think most people would consider each Paris to be separate entities and therefore would have a different identifier to differentiate them:

```
Region ( key = region_id ):
{ region_id = 'R01', region_name = 'France' };
{ region_id = 'R02', region_name = 'Texas' };

City ( key = ??? ):
{ city_id = 'C01', city_name = 'Paris', region_id = 'R01' };
{ city_id = 'C02', city_name = 'Paris', region_id = 'R02' };
```

Even given the above table, I too would be slightly unclear about the key to the City. I think the relation variable 'does too much'; ideally we would have a second relvar to model the relationship between a city and its region:

```
Region ( key = region_id ):
{ region_id = 'R01', region_name = 'France' };
{ region_id = 'R02', region_name = 'Texas' };

City ( key = city_id ):
{ city_id = 'C01', city_name = 'Paris' };
{ city_id = 'C02', city_name = 'Paris' };

CityRegion ( key = city_id ):
{ city_id = 'C01', region_id = 'R01' };
{ city_id = 'C02', region_id = 'R02' };
```

The above is now fully normalized (actually in 6NF).

Comment: In 1:n relationship there is not need for a separate table connecting cities and regions. The explanation for having a relationship table is too scientific and nothing to do with practicality.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of `city_id` and `region_id` fields can be candidate key in the `city` depending on how you define the 2 fields (your post does not say anything about that) because

> A Candidate Key can be any column or a combination of columns that can qualify as unique key in database. There can be multiple Candidate Keys in one table. Each Candidate Key can qualify as Primary Key.

Source: [Difference Between Candidate Keys and Primary Key In Simple Words](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/10/22/sql-server-difference-candidate-keys-primary-key-simple-words/)

You can define the `city_id` alone to be unique (auto_increment probably), but you can also define only a combination of the 2 fields unique.

However, I would not do the latter because if you recategorise a city (moves from one region to another), then you may have to change the city_id component as well.

Comment: I didnot get the last point if i move a city from say region 1 to region 2 then only region_id will be changed for city,why city_id will be changed

Comment: If you use a combination of city_id and region_id to be your PK, then you may have 2 records with city_id - region_id combination of (1,1) - (1,2). Now, if you were to move city (1,1) to region 2, you cannot simply change the region_id to 2, because you already have city (1,2). You also need to change the city_id in this case and have a (2,2).

Comment: that means keeping city id as primary key will make it in 2 nf

Comment: Yep, because then the city name will be fully functionally dependent on the PK and that's the whole point.

Comment: I don't think much of the linked article. Relational theory moved away from the concept of 'primary' keys long ago (notice the OP doesn't mention 'primary' either?), whereas the article suggests you identify candidate keys, choose one to be 'primary' (based on dubious criteria IMO) then drop all the candidate keys i.e. I dont think the author gets the idea that a relvar can have more than one key!

Comment: I used the explanation as to what a candidate key is from that article because that's a lot simpler than a scientific definition. From practical point of view it works.

Comment: To [quote Chris Date](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Uds1DyR0U8IC&pg=PA155&dq="normalization+is+scientific+of+course"): "database design is not my favorite subject. The reason is that so little of design practice is truly scientific; normalization is scientific of course but not much else is." Why are you answering a question on normalization if you are not interested in things scientific?!

Comment: Normalisation is not just scientific, it has its practical uses. However, I do not like recommendations on actual db design just on scientific basis, if that approach goes against common sense.